# Session timeout throws server error in sitecore 9.3

Tags: session-state

[image]

I updated the `session timeout` to *60 minutes* in the `sessionState` section of `web.config`. After the *60 minutes* of time out, the application throws a *server error* with no event log captured. but the same *works as expected* when the *timeout was 20 minutes*. This application is on `Sitecore 9.3`.

What might be causing this?

Code snippet updated

Comment: Please share more details like the server error snapshot you get and config update you made to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Is this in test or production environment? A larger session means more users session will be stored in memory, so this could possibly lead to memory issue. The server error will give an indiciator as to the cause.

Comment: Added additional information, it is happening in non production too

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921362/159153

Here is the text from that answer:

> I am also facing the same issue with Sitecore 9.3. You can try the
> below solution if it works.
>
> Set `ExpireTimeSpan` in `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config` which is
> given below for both "PreviewCookieAuthentication" and
> "CookieAuthentication" to `00:20:00`.
>
> Then set in `sitecore.config`.
>
> It should work for 20 minutes. I am facing an issue when I increase
> the timeout value from 20 to 30 minutes.